# How to Mount ISOs, copy files to guests and invoke scripts on Cloud Server

Tags: vmware, powercli, vcloud-director-rest-api

I am trying to port/adapt some PowerCLI scripts previously used with vSphere to be used with a Cloud Server.

Many of the cmdlets used with vCenter seem to have corresponding versions for cloud (Connect-CIServer, Get-CIVapp, Start-CIVM, etc.)

However, there are a few things I need to do which do not seem to have matching cmdlets...

Specifically, I am trying to figure out how I can mount an ISO (that already exists in a Catalog). I also need to copy a zip archive to a guest and then invoke a PowerShell script to expand the archive and finally execute a script contained inside the expanded archive. This was all pretty trivial to do in vCenter...

Here's the list of cmdlets which I am trying to use with Cloud Server, but can't because the types they are expecting are not compatible with the Cloud types:

- Get-CDDrive
- Set-CDDrive
- Copy-VMGuestFile
- Invoke-VMScript

Do I need to somehow call the API directly? Is that something I can leverage the Get-CIView cmdlet to assist with?

Any help would be most appreciated!